# nester for loop in django template not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a JSON file rendered to the template page from JSON. The template looks like the following. The JSON is named by `no_of_line`.

```
{
  'teamcenter_author': {
    '02/02/2019 11:50': {
        'server1': {
            'count': 1
        }
    },
    '02/02/2019 11:55': {
        'server1': {
            'count': 1
        }
    },
    '02/02/2019 12:00': {
        'server1': {
            'count': 1
        }
    },
    '02/02/2019 12:05': {
        'server1': {
            'count': 1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am using following for loop to access the count under each server of each date.

```
 {% for timestamp in no_of_line.teamcenter_author %}
  {% for server in no_of_line.teamcenter_author.timestamp %}
    {{server.count}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I get a blank output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are having server1 and count same in all the dictionary. You don't need to pass `no_of_line` in `for loop` Try below code:

JSON:

```
no_of_line = {"teamcenter_author":{"02/02/2019 11:50":{"server1":{"count":1}},"02/02/2019 11:55":{"server1":{"count":1}},"02/02/2019 12:00":{"server1":{"count":1}},"02/02/2019 12:05":{"server1":{"count":1}}}}
```

Code:

```
{% for key, value in teamcenter_author.items %}
  {% for key_2,value_2 in value.items %}
       <h>{{value_2.count}}</h>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not working. could it be because of the space in the data of timestamp??

Comment: Could be. Try to remove those spaces and run once

Comment: Your json is missing a bracket in the end

Comment: that was an extra one i got while pasting here

Comment: Updated my solution @AshishGupta. Pls check now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will work, b/c you have a key/value and not an array, but try accessing the timestamp instead of the full nav

```
{% for timestamp in no_of_line.teamcenter_author %}
  {% for server in timestamp %}
    {{server.count}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: no it does not work, as timestamp will contain only '02/02/2019 11:55' and the second loop will only print alphabets/digits/letters of '02/02/2019 11:55'.

Comment: can u transform that in an array of timestamps?

Comment: could it be because of the space in the data of timestamp??

Comment: are u sure your json is valid?

Comment: yepp.  i missed a { while pasting here

Comment: now it is visible invalid... you dont have the oppening bracket

Comment: the json is generated byr 4.5 lakh line of log. and that is correct. please ignore the brackets for now